# Cannot apply styles to tag pre in safari

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit, pre

I have the following issue:
I'm using tag pre to display some information.

```
<pre class="maze align-center">
* * * *** * ******* * * * * * * * **  * * **  * * **  * * * * * * * * *** * * * * * * * * * * * * * * ***** * * * **  * * * * *** * * * * * * * * * * * * * ****
*       *       *                  **      **      **                   *                               *          **      **   *      *                      **
* *** **  *** **  *** ** **** **  *** **  *** **  *** ** **** ** **** **  *** **  *** ** **** ** **** **  *** **  *** **  *** **  *** ** **** ** **** **  *** **
etc...
</pre>
```

My styles:

```
pre, code {font-family:monospace, monospace;}
.maze { line-height: 7px; border: 0; font-size: 9px; }
.align-center{ text-align: center; }
```

The problem is that styles are not applied to `.maze` in safari under MacOS. Note that everything is fine in other browsers and in safari under Windows.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine in Safari to me? From top to bottom - Firefox, Safari, Chrome

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxwwV.png

Mac OSX 10.6.8.

Seems Firefox is your dodgy one?